# Is this question not off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I feel that this question should be considered off-topic and want to close it, but I can't decide on what specific reason to choose for the off-topic vote as none seem to fit. Please guide me on this.

The question in question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348909/who-are-bogdan-and-bj%C3%B6rn-from-the-b-in-the-erlang-beam-vm

While on some level it might be fun to know, it's rather esoteric and not very useful information.

Comment: Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

Comment: @OneWay That was my feeling too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look on-topic at all.  Referencing [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it doesn't fit into the categories for "OK to ask here on Stack Overflow".

There's nothing here in terms of actual programming information, and while it might be fun to learn, I'm thinking of using a custom flag for this one.

In cases like this, if the question really *is* off-topic, but there's no suitable close reason for it, a custom  close reason is acceptable.

Comment: That was my feeling too, I guess a custom flag might be the best fit then.